# Audio and video chat in Google talk

Tags: video, audio, chat, google-talk

I use Google talk for chatting with other gmail users.  Is there a way tha I can use audio and video in Google talk as well so that they can see my picture and hear my voice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Talk has voice chat by default, on Gmail you can use video/audio chat by installing the video chat plugin from here http://www.google.com/talk/

According to Google video is supported only on Gmail for now http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=69432, they may make it available on Talk soon.